# DataGridView Index was out of range. Must be non-negative

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I got a DataGridView in my win form and i am using cell click event to get the value of Ticket Number from the selected to perform deletion everything works fine but when i click on column header:
[image]

i get this error

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index'
>   [![enter image description here][2]][2]

I get this error because in cell click event:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int indexRow = e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[indexRow]; //Debugger shows error here
        txtDelete.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }
```

So i need help in patching/fixing this little bug.
I am using RowIndex of selected cell

Comment: When the debugger stops on that error... What is the value of `indexRow`?  How many elements are in `dataGridView1.Rows`?

Comment: Check if RowIndex is less than zero and just stop processing

Comment: The row index for column headers is -1 and `datagridView1.Rows[-1]` is invalid. You can simply check if `e.RowIndex<0` then return.

Comment: One little trick I find helpful in these situations is to read the error message and pay attention to what it says is wrong. Then maybe I use the debugger.

Comment: Agree with Ed, the error message seems pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Ed Plunkett sorry for the trouble didnt think about that :) i am kind of new.

Comment: @DourHighArch removed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell click event i was getting indexRow=-1 so i changed the code to:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int indexRow = e.RowIndex;
        if (indexRow>=0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[indexRow];
            txtDelete.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        }

    }
```