# How to emtpy GridView

Tags: c#, gridview

```
GridView2.DataSource = null; 
GridView2.DataBind();
```

I get an error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> Parameter name: index'

I think the above code I mentioned will empty the `GridView`.

Comment: Where are you getting that error? It is possible that there's an event handler attempting to access current row by index. See [DataGridView Index was out of range. Must be non-negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334555/datagridview-index-was-out-of-range-must-be-non-negative)